# Should I annotate configuration class as @Configuration for testing?

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, spring-data, spring-java-config

I spent some time resolving problem with missing `org.joda.time.DateTime->java.util.Date` converter in Spring Data (which should be enabled by default when Joda-Time is on a classpath). I have found a reason, but it generated a question about `@Configuration` annotation in Spring.

Standard application config using `AbstractMongoConfiguration` from spring-data-mongodb:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class AppConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration { ... }
```

A test which explicit uses AppConfig class (with Spock, but internally mechanisms provided by spring-test are used):

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig)
class JodaDocRepositorySpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private JodaDocRepository jodaDocRepository

    def "save document with DateTime"() {
        given:
            def jodaDoc = new JodaDoc(DateTime.now())
        when:
            def savedJodaDoc = jodaDocRepository.save(jodaDoc)
        then:
            savedJodaDoc.id
    }
}
```

It works fine. But when @Configuration annotation in AppConfig is **removed**/commented:

```
//@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class AppConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration { ... }
```

the test fails with:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException:
No converter found capable of converting from type org.joda.time.DateTime to type java.util.Date
```

AFAIK it is not needed to use `@Configuration` for the configuration class when it is explicit registered in the context (by classes in `@ContextConfiguration` or a `register()` method in `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`). The classes are processed anyway and all declared beans are found. It is sometimes useful to not use `@Configuration` to prevent detecting by a component scan when there are 2 similar configuration classes in the same packages in a test context used by different tests.

Therefor I think it could a bug in Spring which causes to different internal beans processing in the context depending on an usage or not a `@Configuration` annotation. I compared Spring logs from these two cases and there are some differences, but I'm not able to determine what are they caused by in the Spring internal classes. Before a bug submission I would like to ask:

**My question.** Is there an explicable reason why Spring for the same configuration class (pointed explicit in `@ContextConfiguration`) uses (or not) converters for Joda-Time depending on an existence of a `@Configuration` annotation?

I created also a [quickstart project](https://github.com/szpak/code-examples-and-poc/tree/master/spring-data-mongo-joda-time) reproducing the issue. spring-data-mongodb 1.3.3, spring 4.0.0, joda-time 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's everything OK in this behaviour. `AbstractMongoConfiguration` is annotated by `@Configuration`, but in fact this annotation is not `@Inherited`, so you have to explicitly annotate your class.

When you remove `@Configuration` annotation then your `AppConfig` class is not a **full** configuration. It's processes as a **lite** configuration just because it contains methods annotated by `@Bean` - please refer to methods in `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils`

- `isFullConfigurationCandidate()`
- `isLiteConfigurationCandidate()`
- `isFullConfigurationClass()`

Finally only **full** (annotated by `@Configuration`) configuration classes are processes and enhanced by configuration post processors - look at `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses()`