# Spring Data MongoDB doesn't see enabled by default Joda-Time converter

Tags: java, spring, jodatime, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I try to just save a document with org.joda.time.DateTime field from Joda-Time.

```
@Document
public class JodaDoc {

    @Id
    private BigInteger id;

    private String dateAsString;

    private DateTime date;

    public JodaDoc(String dateAsString, DateTime date) {
        this.dateAsString = dateAsString;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public BigInteger getId() { return id; }

    public String getDateAsString() { return dateAsString; }

    public DateTime getDate() { return date; }
}
```

Standard application config using AbstractMongoConfiguration from spring-data-mongodb:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class AppConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration { ... }
```

A test which explicit uses AppConfig class (with Spock, but internally mechanisms provided by spring-test are used):

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig)
class JodaDocRepositorySpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private JodaDocRepository jodaDocRepository

    def "save document with DateTime"() {
        given:
            def jodaDoc = new JodaDoc(DateTime.now())
        when:
            def savedJodaDoc = jodaDocRepository.save(jodaDoc)
        then:
            savedJodaDoc.id
    }
}
```

Joda-Time converters in Spring Data MongoDB (and also in Spring Core itself) should be enabled by [default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/CustomConversions.java#L105) when Joda-Time jar is on a classpath. Unfortunately my test fails with:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException:
No converter found capable of converting from type org.joda.time.DateTime to type java.util.Date
```

I tried to add DefaultFormattingConversionService:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
}
```

ConversionServiceFactoryBean and a few other things with no effect. I wasn't able to find an answer on StackOverflow.

**Question**. Why Spring Data MongoDB doesn't see a standard `org.joda.time.DateTime -> java.util.Date` conveter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me some time and I want to share the solution with others.

I created a small quickstart application and wasn't able to reproduce the issue. At the end I discovered that the problem was a missing `@Configuration` annotation in my configuration class. With:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class AppConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration { ... }
```

it just works fine.

I often have omitted `@Configuration` for the configuration class when it is explicit registered in the context (by classes in `@ContextConfiguration` or a `register()` method in `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext)`. The classes were processed anyway and all declared beans are found. It is sometimes useful to not use `@Configuration` to prevent detecting by a component scan when there are 2 similar configuration classes in the same packages in a test context used by different tests. It generated an another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21034018/313516) as I am not sure if it is a desired behavior.

Comment: There is an interesting answer the [mentioned question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21034018/313516).